# How to measure mispredictions for a single branch on Linux?

Tags: linux, profiling, perf, branch-prediction

I know that I can get the total percentage of branch mispredictions during the execution of a program with `perf stat`. But how can I get the statistics for a specific branch (`if` or `switch` statement in C code)?

Answer (score 9):

You can sample on the `branch-misses` event:

`sudo perf record -e branch-misses <yourapp>`

and then report it (and even selecting the function you're interested in):

`sudo perf report -n --symbols=<yourfunction>`

There you can access the annotated code and get some statistics for a given branch. Or directly `annotate` it with the perf command with `--symbol` option.

Comment: It can be more useful to record both `branches` and `branch-misses` events: `sudo perf record -e branches,branch-misses`. With `--symbol` there will be total counts for the function; in annotated code there will be percents of total counts for current function.